# does the Keil cortex-m C compiler always compile functions address 4-byte align?

Tags: arm, keil, iar, cortex-m

I am trying to copy a function from FLASH to memory, if i use word copying it will be faster, but he STM and LDM instructions require the addresses are 4-byte aligned, so i wonder generally comtex-m C compiler such as Keil/IAR or GNU are always compile the function as 4 bytes aligned?

Comment: generally yes, but the compiler does what you tell it and there are ways to tell it wrong that it cant figure out.  Ideally you want to use 4 word stm/ldms and just do it yourself in assembly.  8 is even better depending on the size but you have to store all of them on the stack, and the loop/copy code only has a few registers left.  so 4 words per stm/ldm is a common balance you see in memcpy libraries and other places.  I have/know of one arm core that even if you do more than 4 words it breaks the instruction into 4 word transfers for writes, but will do 8 or more for reads...

Comment: I don't believe the arm calling conventions require functions to be on a word boundary, except for ISR handlers.  Refer to the arm documentation for calling conventions for the architecture revision you're interested in for complete details.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since Cortex-M processors use 16-bit Thumb instructions, the label of a subroutine will be 2-byte aligned only.

In your case, if you want to enforce 4-byte alignment to improve data transfer speed, you can place the function(s) into a separate section. The section will be 4-byte aligned by default. On how to do that, please refer to [Placement of code and data with **attribute**((section("name")))](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474m/pge1362066000009.html) and [**attribute**((section("name"))) function attribute](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0375g/chr1359124977848.html)